# Crash when adding string from regex capture to attributed string

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to create a link in an attributed string using:

```
    matches = regex.matches(in: strings, options: [], range: NSRange(strings.startIndex..., in: strings))

        for match in matches {

            rangeBetweenQuotes = match.range(at: 1)

            let swiftRange = Range(rangeBetweenQuotes, in: strings)!

            let link:String = String(strings[swiftRange])

              attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: link, range: rangeBetweenQuotes)

        }
```

I know the foregoing works if I simply add a font attribute rather than a link.  So my regex works. However, when adding a link attribute I run into problems.  When I compile the code as written above and run the app, I tap the link and get an error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0. It appears in the app delegate class.

As far as I can tell, last two lines of code are throwing the error.

```
     let link:String = String(strings[swiftRange])

          attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: link, range:  rangeBetweenQuotes)
```

To debug, I placed a breakpoint in between the last two lines of code above. I can see that the variable `link` contains the correct string. The string is also found in the `value` parameter of `addAttribute`.

The error is thrown during runtime when the link is tapped.  I know this is the case because I can replace or assign `link` with a string literal, i.e. `"test"`, and the link works fine, and I am able to use

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
```

to assign the "test" string literal to an outlet.

Using the debugger, I came across the following which I found in a drill-down menu within the `link` variable in the `value` parameter of `addAttribute.`

**(BridgeObject) _object = extracting data from value failed**

This suggests there is something wrong with the variable. No?

I tried using `URL(string:"")` to convert the `link` variable of type `String` to a `URL`, which did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer concerns whether the URL type in the following function is compatible with whatever type is passed into it.

```
 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool
```

Th code below works without throwing an error.  Take a look at **URL(fileURLWithPath: )**

```
     ... let swiftRange = Range(rangeBetweenQuotes, in: strings)!

        let link:String = String(strings[swiftRange])

          let link2 = URL(fileURLWithPath: link)

             attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: link2, range: rangeBetweenQuotes)
```

The crash I kept getting did not originate from an error in executing the function **addAttribute** parameter **value** which takes **Any** object type. In debugging the error, I found that the parameter **value** in **addAttribute** contained the string value I passed into it. As mentioned above, the issue originated in the function:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool
```

which takes a URL. While I attempted to convert the string type **link** to a URL using

```
URL(string:"")
```

the conversion did not work. I kept getting a null value which of course threw an error when tapping on the link. However, I can safely pass a variable into the parameter **shouldInteractWith URL:URL** when the string type variable
is converted to a **URL** using:

```
 URL(fileURLWithPath: link)
```

I still do not understand why **shouldInteractWith URL:URL** accepts a string literal while String(string[swiftRange]), *supra*, does not work. Any thoughts?

**EDIT ... further explanation**

I know the answer to why **URL** type accepts one string literal while not another.  A valid **URL** type cannot have a space in a string.  **URL(fileURLWithPath:)** works because it fills white space with %20.

I hope this helps someone down the road.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be the conversion `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>` and vice versa. You are strongly discouraged from using `string.count` and the `NSString` detour.

There are convenience APIs to convert the types safely

```
matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
```

and

```
let swiftRange = Range(rangeBetweenQuotes, in: string)!
let link = String(string[swiftRange])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I implemented your recommendations with no luck.  Notwithstanding, I will continue to use the suggested APIs.  Thank you for weighing in on the matter.  -Keith